# Laravel Form package - how save data from checkbox

Tags: database, forms, laravel, checkbox, foreach

Please help me. How save data from form? If its standard from, everything works, but my code for form is:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'fill2', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'result', ]) !!}
            @forelse ($quests as $quest)
                @if($post->form_id == $quest->form_id)
                    <blockquote class="blockquote bq-success">
                        <p class="bq-title"></p>
                        <p>{{$quest->quest_name}}</p>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                            @foreach($responses as $response)
                                @if($quest->quest_id == $response->quest_id)
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>

                                                <input type="{{$response->response_type}}" name="{{$response->id}}"></th>
                                            <th><label class="radio-inline">{{$response->response}}</label></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                                <small>{{notempty ($quest->quest_note)}}</small>
                        </div>
                    </blockquote>
                @endif


            @empty
            @endforelse

            {!! Form::button('Send', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my code in controller is

```
$result = Auth::user()->results()->create($request->all() ?: []);
    return $result->toArray();
```

And result:
{"user_id":4,"id":20} - only this is saving to database

I have maybe 30 checkboxs, but anything no save to database, and no send to post request.  Any idea?

Comment: if you dd($request->all()) in your controller, what does it show?

Comment: It doesn't look like your input fields actually have a value attribute specified. Change the name to something shared, e.g. `whatever[]` and set `value="{{ $response->id }}"`

Comment: @pseudoanime : array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "EoFavpG1IcoWJsh9h39UYmlXiDvVpYdaOOxniIUx"
  69 => "on"
  72 => "on"
  74 => "on"
  77 => null
  85 => null
  89 => null
  90 => "on"
  92 => "on"
  93 => null
]      And save to database: user_id - 4 (is OK) and form_id  - 0